# Creating dynamic elastic search query in php

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I have to create the following elastic search query in php:

```
$parameters = [
    'index' => 'myindex',
    'from' => 0,
    'size' => 60,
    'body' => [
        'query' => [
            'bool' => [
                'filter' => [[
                'bool' => [
                    'must' => [
                        $myvariable,
                        ['nested' => [
                                'path' => 'sh',
                                'query' => [
                                    'bool' => [
                                        'filter' => [
                                            ['term' => ['sh.keyword' => 'PK']]
                                        ]
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
                    ]],
            ]
        ],
        "sort" => [
            ["score" => ["mode" => "avg"]]
        ]
    ]
];
```

Where $myvariable should be:

```
['bool'=>
  ['should'=>[
      ['term'=> ['id'=> {$id1}]],
      ['term'=> ['id'=> {$id2}]],
          ],
    'minimum_should_match'=> 1
  ]
]
```

I do not want to hardcode the values as it completely depends on the user whether she/he will choose the mentioned values in drop down or not.

**What I tried?**

I tried to create the inner part, that is the term part:

```
$countofids = count($combined_array['ids']);


if ($countofids != 0) {

for ($i = 0; $i < $countofids ; $i++) {

    if ($i == 0) {
        $myvariable= array('term' => array('id' => $combined_array['ids'][$i]));
    } else {
         array_push($myvariable, $combined_array['ids'][$i]);
    }
}
```

}

But, it does not work as expected. I get:

```
['term'=> ['id'=> {$id1}]]
```

But, further, I do not get the required result. Moreover, I don't know how to separate them by comma. 
Can anyone provide a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've reworked the code slightly to make it easier to read, but the idea is that you were just overwriting `$myvariable` each time.  I've included some test data for my own purposes and show what it's doing, but the main part is to replace the code you already have...

```
$combined_array = ['ids' => [1,2]];

if (count($combined_array['ids']) != 0) {
    // Define array for terms
    $myvariable = [];
    foreach ( $combined_array['ids'] as $id ) {
        // Add new term to existing list
        $myvariable[]= array('term' => array('id' => $id));
    }
    // Combine data with main structure
    $myvariable = [ 'bool' => ['should' => $myvariable,
        'minimum_should_match'=> 1]
    ];
}

print_r($myvariable);
```

which gives...

```
Array
(
    [bool] => Array
        (
            [should] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [term] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 1
                                )
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [term] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 2
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

If I've made any incorrect assumptions then let me know and I will sort them out.

Comment: Thanks for the response! How can I integrate ''minimum_should_match'=> 1'?

Comment: I've added in the value, can you check it.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I saw the old one. Thanks! I will just check the result.